# Crystal Reports - Failed to retrieve data from the database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports XI.  When I execute the report from my desktop version, I get

> Failed to retrieve data from the database.

If I run it from the internet, the report runs to completion.  I am unable to determine what the problem is. I have tried verifying the database (`database table cannot be found error`).

Updating the stored procedure `(database object cannot be accessed error)`,

Deleting and adding the stored procedure without any success.

The only thing I'm trying to do is add a field to the report from the existing stored procedure.  No changes have been made to the stored procedure.  Any suggestions?

Comment: does store proc execute outside of the report? if yes then something wrong with a new column

Comment: Thank you for your response.  No, the stored procedure executes within the report.  No changes were made to the stored procedure.  I was attempting to drag and drop a field that wasn't previously included on the report.  When I select print preview to execute the report, I immediately get the failed to retrieve data error.

Comment: check the database username and password.. there is a chance that password was different during development and now when you are trying to open

Comment: Thanks to Hiten004 and Siva for your help.  I deleted, then added the ODBC connection and was able to successfully run the report without any errors.